Meaning of tags starting with §§ and § in syntax structure software
So I have been working with a syntax parsing software called VISL (https://edu.visl.dk/visl/en/parsing/automatic/parse.php) to generate data about every word in a paragraph. I'm programming the software to do this (that scrapes VISL) and I have a list of all the tags I'll have to translate back to normal English. 
Now, there are two types of tags that I do not have a list of: they only appear when the software is set to Full Semantic Parser (w/ ontology, case roles and frames), and they start with § and §§. If anyone could tell me what these tags mean and where I could get a list of them, I would be grateful.
Also, if this question is not meant to be posted here but on another Stack site, then please refer me.
